# Web application using Angular 15 and Keycloak 20.0.5 | Redirects to the login page after a page refresh

Tags: angular, kubernetes, nginx, keycloak, keycloak-js

I'm developing a web application using Angular 15 and Spring Boot. As the IAM solution we are using Keycloak(20.0.5). We have created a public client for the web application (`web-application`). We have deployed the angular application, keycloak and other spring boot microservice in Kubernetes(in a EKS cluster).

Frontend Kubernetes service name - `main-frontend-service`

**Please also note** that application and keycloak deployed in different clusters.

***Web application URL :*** `http://a************.amazonaws.com/main-frontend`

***Keycloak URL :*** `http://b************.amazonaws.com/keycloak-service`

Now we are facing the issue, as user refresh the page or duplicate the page or try to open the page in a new tag, user is being redirected to the login page.

**Please find the following code snippet for the frontend keycloak client related**

```js
import {KeycloakService} from "keycloak-angular";
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";

export function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () => keycloak.init({
    config: {
      url: `${environment.keycloakConfig.url}`,
      realm: `${environment.keycloakConfig.realm}`,
      clientId: `${environment.keycloakConfig.clientId}`,
    },
    initOptions: {
      // checkLoginIframe: true,
      // checkLoginIframeInterval: 300,
      onLoad: 'login-required',
      // silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
      //   window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html'
    },
  });
}
```

We have tried the currently suggested solutions for this issue and we were unable to find a solution.

**Please find the keycloak client configurations**

***Root URL :*** `http://a************.amazonaws.com/main-frontend`

***Redirect URL :*** `/main-frontend`

[image]

**Please also find nginx configurations for main-frontend-service in kubernetes**

```js
paths:
- backend:
    service:
      name: main-frontend-service
      port:
        number: 80
  path: /(/|$)(.*)
  pathType: Prefix
- backend:
    service:
      name: main-frontend-service
      port:
        number: 80
  path: /main-frontend(/|$)(.*)
  pathType: Prefix
```

**EDITED**

***Web application(when up it locally) is working fine in localhost as expected***

Please find the current architecture. Were all the backend API calls are going through the `spring-gateway-service` which integrated with spring security and keycloak.

Sample API : `http:a*********.amazonaws.com/gateway-service/service-a/api/<endpoint>`

[image]

I really appreciate if you can give help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The tokens in your Angular app are not shared between tabs, and this is expected: imagine if any other javascript code running in any other tab could access your tokens...

You could expect that the user session with current browser remains opened on Keycloak and that the `authorization_code` flow completes silently for the new tab (new tokens are delivered to the new public client instance without the need for the user to enter credentials).

You could investigate why this new tab doesn't bind to the existing session on Keycloak (or why this session has ended), but **[usage of public clients is discouraged by Spring Security team](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390)** (and many others). Recommended alternative is to use a **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend configured as an OAuth2 confidential client between **S**ingle **P**age **A**pplications and resource servers.

I wrote [a tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) using `spring-cloud-gateway` with the `TokenRelay` filter to serve as BFF between an Angular app and a Spring resource server. The exact same pattern is applied in [this project](https://github.com/ch4mpy/quiz) which I [deploy on K8s](https://quiz.c4-soft.com/ui/quizzes). Keycloak is running in its own namespace (same cluster, but it would behave the same in a different one). You can try creating an account, logging in and opening a new tab, you'll be connected.

Comment: Hi @ch4mp, appreciate your help and i have updated the question. We are currently using a spring cloud gateway in our solution. do we need to include frontend routes as well in the gateway filters?

Comment: No, you don't _have to_, but routing UI through the gateway removes the need for CORS configuration on resource servers (from the browser perspective, UI and REST requests to the API have the same origin: the gateway). This CORS configuration being quite a pain to get working through the gateway, I strongly advise that you route the Angular assets through the gateway (at least as a first step, modifying your conf just for CORS and other UI origin when you are sure that everything else works).

Comment: Noted with thanks @ch4mp, however this is working fine in localhost. I not sure is there any configuration that I've missed while deploying this in cloud